# Python Assistance With Program

Tags: python

I am getting the correct answer output for the first example, but not the next 2. Can anyone tell me why? The input is the velocity and mass at rest. Here are the examples:

***Example #1:***

Velocity as a % of the speed of light: 0
Mass of the spaceship at rest (kg): 70000
Mass of spaceship: 70000.000 kg
Time to travel to Alpha Centauri: 4.300 light years
Time to travel to Barnard's Star: 6.000 light years
Time to travel to Betelgeuse: 309.000 light years
Time to travel to Andromeda Galaxy: 2000000.000 light years

***Example # 2:***

Velocity as a % of the speed of light: 50
Mass of the spaceship at rest (kg): 70000
Mass of spaceship: 80829.038 kg
Time to travel to Alpha Centauri: 3.724 light years
Time to travel to Barnard's Star: 5.196 light years
Time to travel to Betelgeuse: 267.602 light years
Time to travel to Andromeda Galaxy: 1732050.808 light years

***Example #3:***

Velocity as a % of the speed of light: 99.99
Mass of the spaceship at rest (kg): 70000
Mass of spaceship: 4949871.217 kg
Time to travel to Alpha Centauri: 0.061 light years
Time to travel to Barnard's Star: 0.085 light years
Time to travel to Betelgeuse: 4.370 light years
Time to travel to Andromeda Galaxy: 28283.564 light years

**Here is my code:**

```
def einstein_factor(velocity):
    # Calculate the Einstein factor based on velocity
    c = 299792458  # Speed of light in meters per second
    v = velocity * c / 100.0  # Convert percentage to actual velocity
    factor = 1 / (1 - (v**2 / c**2)) ** 0.5
    return factor

def calculate_travel_time(distance, velocity):
    #Calculate the time it takes to travel a certain distance
    c = 299792458  # Speed of light in meters per second
    v = velocity * c / 100.0  # Convert percentage to actual velocity
    time = distance / ((1 - (v**2 / c**2)) **0.5)
    return time

def main():
    #Input velocity as percent of speed of light and the mass
    velocity = float(input("Velocity as a % of the speed of light: "))
    mass = float(input("Mass of the spaceship at rest (kg): "))

    #Output mass of spaceship
    factor = einstein_factor(velocity)
    traveling_mass = mass * factor
    print("Mass of Spaceship: {:.3f}".format(traveling_mass))

    #Output the times in light years
    alpha_centauri_time = calculate_travel_time(4.3, velocity)
    barnards_star_time = calculate_travel_time(6.0, velocity)
    betelgeuse_time = calculate_travel_time(309, velocity)
    andromeda_galaxy_time = calculate_travel_time(2000000, velocity)

    print("Time to Alpha Centauri: {:.3f} light years".format(alpha_centauri_time))
    print("Time to Barnard's Star: {:.3f} light years".format(barnards_star_time))
    print("Time to Betelgeuse: {:.3f} light years".format(betelgeuse_time))
    print("Time to Andromeda Galaxy: {:.3f} light years".format(andromeda_galaxy_time))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: [ask] and [mre]

Comment: Also what's with the java tag? Don't spam tags.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add **()** such as v = (velocity * c) / 100.0, if not this will give different results.

I do not know the formula but this is the an issue I have find out. Please run the code and check this out?

```
def einstein_factor(velocity):
    # Calculate the Einstein factor based on velocity
    c = 299792458  # Speed of light in meters per second
    v = (velocity * c) / 100.0  # Convert percentage to actual velocity
    factor = 1 / ((1 - (v**2 / c**2)) ** 0.5)
    return factor

def calculate_travel_time(distance, velocity):
    #Calculate the time it takes to travel a certain distance
    c = 299792458  # Speed of light in meters per second
    v = (velocity * c) / 100.0  # Convert percentage to actual velocity
    time = distance / ((1 - (v**2 / c**2)) ** 0.5)
    return time

def main():
    #Input velocity as percent of speed of light and the mass
    velocity = float(input("Velocity as a % of the speed of light: "))
    mass = float(input("Mass of the spaceship at rest (kg): "))

    #Output mass of spaceship
    factor = einstein_factor(velocity)
    traveling_mass = mass * factor
    print("Mass of Spaceship: {:.3f}".format(traveling_mass))

    #Output the times in light years
    alpha_centauri_time = calculate_travel_time(4.3, velocity)
    barnards_star_time = calculate_travel_time(6.0, velocity)
    betelgeuse_time = calculate_travel_time(309, velocity)
    andromeda_galaxy_time = calculate_travel_time(2000000, velocity)

    print("Time to Alpha Centauri: {:.3f} light years".format(alpha_centauri_time))
    print("Time to Barnard's Star: {:.3f} light years".format(barnards_star_time))
    print("Time to Betelgeuse: {:.3f} light years".format(betelgeuse_time))
    print("Time to Andromeda Galaxy: {:.3f} light years".format(andromeda_galaxy_time))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```